# Linker error with templated return type

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, linker-errors

I'm playing with trailing return types. If I put the following code into a header file and add it to a library project, then unit test, everything works fine . . .

```
namespace ContainerStats {

// The trailing return type allows one to be less verbose relative to
// std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type,
//            typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>
template<typename Iter>
auto summean(Iter first1, Iter last1)->decltype( std::make_tuple(*first1, *first1) )
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
    value_type sum = std::accumulate(first1, last1, value_type());
    value_type mean = sum / (last1-first1);

    return std::make_tuple(sum, mean);
}

}
```

However, if I split definition and implementation into header . . .

```
// .h
namespace ContainerStats {
template<typename Iter>
auto summean(Iter first1, Iter last1)->decltype( std::make_tuple(*first1, *first1) );
}
```

and cpp . . .

```
template<typename Iter>
auto ContainerStats::summean(Iter first1, Iter last1)->decltype( std::make_tuple(*first1, *first1) )
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
    value_type sum = std::accumulate(first1, last1, value_type());
    value_type mean = sum / (last1-first1);

    return std::make_tuple(sum, mean);
}
```

Then, I end up with a curious linker error . .

```
Linking CXX static library libDemo.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libDemo.a(ContainerStats.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libDemo.a(ContainerStats.cpp.o) has no symbols

Linking CXX executable demo_tests
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "decltype(std::make_tuple(*(fp)*(fp))) ContainerStats::summean<std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*> >(std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*>)", referenced from:
      summean_sum_Test::TestBody() in stats_test.cpp.o
      summean_mean_Test::TestBody() in stats_test.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As a sanity check for my build setup, I added a dummy function to the header returning a bool and cpp implementation that just returns `true`. The `has no symbols` part of the error vanishes, but the `symbols not found` part remains related to the function with the trailing return type.

**EDIT**

As another check, I just used the more verbose return type (described in the code comment in the first snippet), and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you don't use a trailing return type?

Comment: Same thing, see footnote